# php-mysql version conflicts with Mysql server

Tags: php, mysql

I have php 5.3 and mysql server 5.5 installed.   I need to install php-mysql, but got the following conflict.  How do I resolve this?

```
yum install php-mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.versaweb.com
 * elrepo: elrepo.org
 * extras: yum.phx.singlehop.com
 * updates: yum.phx.singlehop.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6_2.8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.8 for package: php-mysql-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: php-mysql-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: php-mysql-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.61-1.el6_2.1 will be installed
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6_2.5 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.5 for package: php-5.3.3-3.el6_2.5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.5 for package: php-cli-5.3.3-3.el6_2.5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.5 for package: php-pdo-5.3.3-3.el6_2.5.x86_64
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6_2.8 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6_2.5 will be updated
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6_2.8 will be an update
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6_2.5 will be updated
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6_2.8 will be an update
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6_2.5 will be updated
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6_2.8 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

===============================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                       Arch                                      Version                                              Repository                                  Size
===============================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 php-mysql                                     x86_64                                    5.3.3-3.el6_2.8                                      updates                                     79 k
Installing for dependencies:
 mysql-libs                                    x86_64                                    5.1.61-1.el6_2.1                                     updates                                    1.2 M
Updating for dependencies:
 php                                           x86_64                                    5.3.3-3.el6_2.8                                      updates                                    1.1 M
 php-cli                                       x86_64                                    5.3.3-3.el6_2.8                                      updates                                    2.2 M
 php-common                                    x86_64                                    5.3.3-3.el6_2.8                                      updates                                    522 k
 php-pdo                                       x86_64                                    5.3.3-3.el6_2.8                                      updates                                     73 k

Transaction Summary
===============================================================================================================================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)
Upgrade       4 Package(s)

Total size: 5.2 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/README from install of mysql-libs-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
```

Comment: You already have mySQL installed?

Comment: @Filype: yes and I can not reinstall MySQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest downloading a `shared-compat` package from http://dev.mysql.com/ and replacing the default `mysql-libs` with that. `shared-compat` provides all versions of MySQL client libraries and it should satisfy any future software upgrades or installations. For example use the package called `MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.24-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`

To install it, remove the existing `mysql-libs` package while ignoring any dependencies with `rpm -e --nodeps mysql-libs` and immediately install the new package with `rpm -ihv MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.24-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`.

You should of course schedule a maintenance window if the server is handling any production traffic as removing the libraries may cause errors before the new ones are installed.

Later you should also think about replacing the server and client packages to the official ones too to avoid having builds from different vendors.

Answer (score 2):

**I had the similar issue like,**

```
Error: mysql conflicts with MySQL-server
Error: mysql-server conflicts with MySQL-server
```

**It was solved by using these four commands in the terminal**

```
yum remove MySQL-devel* -y
yum remove MySQL-devel-community* -y
yum remove MySQL-client* -y
yum remove MySQL-server* -y
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Upgrading to php 5.4 should work

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall php from source with mysql and mysql pdo enabled, it's always simpler this way.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, trying to upgrade to MySQL server 5.7 but still using PHP 5.3. This command helped me install `php-mysql` properly for this version:

`yum --enablerepo=mysql57-community install php-mysql`

It automatically installed the necessary packages, one of which is `mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64 0:5.7.39-1.el6` (suggested by the user Mushu).