# Installing php5.3 on Centos 5.9 with MySQL 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, centos, php-5.3, centos5

We have MySQL version `5.1.73` runnning on our CentOS `5.9` server and want to install PHP `5.3`. However, when I run `yum install php53-mysql` I get the following error message:

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php53-mysql.x86_64 0:5.3.3-22.el5_10 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php53-pdo for package: php53-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: php53-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: php53-mysql
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.0.95-5.el5_9 set to be updated
---> Package php53-pdo.x86_64 0:5.3.3-22.el5_10 set to be updated
--> Processing Conflict: mysql conflicts MySQL
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
mysql-5.0.95-5.el5_9.x86_64 from base has depsolving problems
  --> mysql conflicts with MySQL-server-community
Error: mysql conflicts with MySQL-server-community
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Hours of googling have not yielded any results as it seems I'm the only one experiencing conflicts between PHP 5.3 and MySQL 5.1. It seems to me that PHP 5.3 wants to install MySQL `5.0` for some reason, but I'm not sure (very new to all this).

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Have you tried the yum suggested commands (skip-broken, package-cleanup)? If you're wanting uninstall the MySQL-server-community version have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17296274/499581

Comment: From what I see it looks like you're trying to install a combined package of php and mysql and you already have mysql installed. Uninstall Mysql and then run yum install php53-mysql

Comment: Thanks for the replies! The problem is that there are several ruby apps on the server which all use the current MySQL installation. I have also tried the yum commands, without luck.

Comment: try to ask at http://serverfault.com/ too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future googlers: Install PHP from the IUS repository: https://iuscommunity.org/pages/IUSClientUsageGuide.html :-)