# Can't enable PDO MySQL extension in CentOS

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've added the following lines in php.ini

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=mysql.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

But I'm still only getting sqlite support in phpinfo(); and a PHP app I'm trying to install shows "PHP PDO MySQL Module:    Not Found".

however `php -m` gives the following list:

```
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the php-mysql package was an error state, I followed the instructions in another answer to resolve it
[php-mysql version conflicts with Mysql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755222/php-mysql-version-conflicts-with-mysql-server)

Answer (score 0):

if using windows just uncomment 
extension_dir = "ext"
in php.ini

Answer (score -1):

You have an CentOS(Red Hat(Linux)). You need to install the php_module like that:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Then do an apache restart Like that:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: What is the windows way to do what?

Comment: do you have php5 running as an apache-module or as a Standalone?

Comment: I suppose.. both?  It's available via apache and via the command line - not sure I understand.   Anyway I don't have APT (I have Yum, and I've been advised if you have yum there is no need to install apt) and the apache service is called httpd, so we might be talking about different environments here.

Comment: apt-get huh for centos?